# Plot EER point in a DET curve using bob python package

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-bob

Sample code:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> import bob.measure
>>> positives = np.random.normal(1,1,100)
>>> negatives = np.random.normal(-1,1,100)
>>> # we assume you have your negatives and positives already split
>>> npoints = 100
>>> bob.measure.plot.det(negatives, positives, npoints, color=(0,0,0), linestyle='-', label='test') 
>>> bob.measure.plot.det_axis([0.01, 40, 0.01, 40]) 
>>> pyplot.xlabel('FAR (%)') 
>>> pyplot.ylabel('FRR (%)') 
>>> pyplot.grid(True)
>>> pyplot.show()
```

This code returns the following image:
[image]

The following functions calculates the EER:

```
eer1 = bob.measure.eer_rocch(negatives, positives)
```

I would like to include this intersection "point" into the curve.
I have tried with:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot
>>> import bob.measure
>>> positives = np.random.normal(1,1,100)
>>> negatives = np.random.normal(-1,1,100)
>>> # we assume you have your negatives and positives already split
>>> npoints = 100
>>> bob.measure.plot.det(negatives, positives, npoints, color=(0,0,0), linestyle='-', label='test') 
>>> bob.measure.plot.det_axis([0.01, 40, 0.01, 40]) 
>>> pyplot.plot(eer1,eer1) 
>>> pyplot.xlabel('FAR (%)') 
>>> pyplot.ylabel('FRR (%)') 
>>> pyplot.grid(True)
>>> pyplot.show()
```

With no success.
I would like to get a figure as in the following example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.measure/-/merge_requests/95 and is included in new versions of bob.measure. To make sure the point falls on the plot, increase the number of points significantly.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
import bob.measure
import numpy as np
npoints = 1000 # use a large number here
positives = np.random.normal(1,1,100)
negatives = np.random.normal(-1,1,100)
bob.measure.plot.det(negatives, positives, npoints, color=(0,0,0), linestyle='-', label='test') 
bob.measure.plot.det_axis([0.01, 40, 0.01, 40])
eer1 = bob.measure.eer(negatives, positives)
# DET plots are in log scale, use ppndf to convert the point
eer2 = bob.measure.ppndf(eer1)
pyplot.plot(eer2, eer2, "o", label=f"EER={eer1*100}%")
pyplot.xlabel('FAR (%)') 
pyplot.ylabel('FRR (%)') 
pyplot.grid(True)
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

[image: DET Plot]